# How to use flutter _pageControler.jumpToPage() from another screen?

Tags: flutter, flutter-pageview

Let's say I have 4 files in my project.

**navbar**, **firstPage**, **secondPage**, **thirdPage**.

In the **navbar** I have a side drawer with *navigation for the pageview* and a *pageview for firstPage secondPage and thirdPage*.

How do I access navbar `PageController.jumpToPage()` from button onTab function in other pages?

Comment: Can you post you code?

Comment: You can pass the PageView Controllers as props to the navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access navbar PageController.jumpToPage() from button onTab function in other pages by 2 ways:

1 passing PageController to the page that have onTab function

2 using dependence injection that can share PageController with any page, have a look at [get_it](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) package for more info.